# Despite I use Take() method, EF Core return all data

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a view in my DB. I have created model of view and call it with `EF Core`. There are  16 rows in view. When I call it with EF Core and use `Take(10)` it returns 10 rows but I look DBSet all rows shows there. For detail here is my code

```
[Table("my_view", Schema ="dbo")]
public class MyView
{

    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

in my action:

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    using (var context = new CCContext())
    {
        var listOfData = context.MyView
                            .AsQueryable().Take(10).ToList();
        return Json(listOfData);
    }
}
```

PS. For some problem I couldn't upload screen of result.(https://m.imgur.com/gallery/xmP3q32)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECn9U.jpg

Comment: what if you try to add an OrderBy?

Comment: I use both AsQueryable() and without it but result is same @MichaelRandall

Comment: Try without ToList();

Comment: try ToList() method before Take(10).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The title says you get all 16 rows, but "it returns 10 rows but I look DBSet all rows shows there" makes it sound like you only get 10.

Comment: @mylee , I tried but same result

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov I just realized what JLe mentioned it should be as expected if you get 10 after using Take(10)

Comment: I think we still need some explaining. What are you trying to accomplish? What is the result that you're getting with this code? "it returns 10 rows but I look DBSet all rows shows there." It should return 10 rows as it is, but what is `DBSet`? Where are you using it?

Comment: @ikerbera I Uploaded screen please look again

Comment: @JLe I uploaded image to explain my opinion. Please look at the image again.

Comment: That makes sense, that's the context without the `Take(10)` so it should have the full data. Now, what does have `listOfData` and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @ikerbera if my view contains 10.000+ data what will be happen? then all rows will come again? I just want to do if I use Take(10) result must be 10. Not all rows need show in MyView DataSet

Comment: You're assigning the `Take(10)` to the variable `listOfData`. `listOfData` is going to have 10 rows. You have to return the `listOfData` variable or somehow do the `Take(10)` in the `View()` code you're returning. It also would help if you can show us that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean `context.MyView` contains all rows, then you are right. Because that is a representation of the table in the DB. However, in your example `listOfData` should contain only 10 rows. If so, then this is as it should be expected.

If the above does not answer your question, please give some more insight and also, what DB provider are you using with EF?

For clarification: 
*The data is not there untill you ask a debugger (or code) to fetch it for you. The only reason you see it is because you ask the debugger to show its contents, and therefor it fetches its contents. It wont if you wont ask it to.*

Comment: @ikerbera I Uploaded screen please look again

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov Based on the screenshot, see my answer above :) context.MyView *should* contain all the data. However *listOfData* should only contain 10 records.

Comment: You should check your varaible listOfData if it contains only 10 items. Post a new screenshot.

Comment: @RoelAbspoel okay if my view contains 10.000+ data what will be happen? then all rows will come again? I just want to do if I use Take(10) result must be 10. Not all rows need show in MyView DataSet

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov if you chose to inspect it then yes. The DbSet is just a representation of the table, so if you ask the debugger to show you the contents it will show the full table. Thats why you use a variable to filter your table in. By asking the DbSet to return only 10 records (Take) it fires off a query to get only 10 records. However, again, if you ask the debugger to show the contents of the DbSet it will fire off a query to select all. The problem you see is not a problem, it is caused because you ask to show the full DbSet.Normally only listOfData would be filled.

Comment: Also, thats why the suggestion to use .ToList() is important, it tells the program to fire off the SQL. If you dont, it will gather whatever statements you add (Take, Orderby, skip, where, etc) and only when .ToList() is called explicitly or implicitly it will make one big statement. (so .Take and .Where are not 2 statements, it will use those to make 1 statement)

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov The data is not there *untill* you ask a debugger (or code) to fetch it for you. The only reason you see it is because you ask the debugger to show its contents, and therefor it fetches its contents. It wont if you wont ask it to.